# How to add Next/Previous buttons for JS Tabs

Tags: javascript, tabs

I want to add **Next/Previous** buttons for **JS** tabs, so users can go to a next tab using these buttons. Also, I want previous button appear only when the second tab opened and next button disappear when the last tab is opened. How can I do that?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().addClass("current");
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
    var tab = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
    $(tab).fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```css
    #tab-1 {
      display: block;
    }
    .tab-content {
      display: none;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
```

```html
 <ul class="tabs-menu" class="articles">
  <li class="current"><a href="#tab-1">tab 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#tab-2">tab 2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#tab-3">tab 3</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#tab-4">tab 4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab">
  <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content">Content 1</div>
  <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">Content 2</div>
  <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">Content 3</div>
  <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">Content 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

we have tried the next previous button for your code
check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/npjxj42j/) link

```
$('#nex').on('click',function(){
     if(count<4)
        {
    $('.tab-content').hide()
    count++;
    $('#tab-'+count).show();
    if(count>1)
        $('#pre').show();
    else
        $('#pre').hide();
        }
});

    $('#pre').on('click',function(){
        if(count>1)
        {
    $('.tab-content').hide()
    count--;
    $('#tab-'+count).show();
    if(count<4)
        $('#nex').show();
    else
        $('#nex').hide();
        }
});
```

Comment: Great! It works in terms of going to next/previous tabs. However, next button is still there when the last tab is opened. Any ideas how to hide it? Same applies to previous button when the 1st tab is opened.

Comment: Sorry I have noticed one more problem. If I click on any of the tabs (e.g tab 2) then if you click on next it doesn't go to tab-3 (which would be the next one). It just jump to the last tab. Any ideas?